# Updating Control from Background worker not working

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have control which i need to update from background worker http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView

But when i set the property or call a method of that control directly,its not getting updated from background worker

```
 imageListView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
 imageListView1.EnsureVisible(0);
```

So i used invoke to update it from GUI thread...

```
  imageListView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    imageListView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
                                    imageListView1.EnsureVisible(0);
                                });
```

This also not working..Please advice

**UPDATE:**

Strangely when i add `MessageBox.Show("hi");` in the first line.. it works

Comment: Is your UI thread free to update the invalidated control? Just for testing purposes try to add an `imageListView1.Refresh();` line, too. If it works, it is a sign that you block the UI thread with some task so it has no time to refresh the invalidated controls.

Comment: @taffer This does not work as well.But strangely when i add `MessageBox.Show("hi");` in the first line.. it works.

Comment: how and where do you create `imageListView1`? besides, "not working" is not really a good description, if at all...

Comment: @JeffRSon I just drag and drop the control to the form.Not working means ... the image list view item is not getting selected.

Comment: Is your DoWork method short enough to be posted completely? Do you get an exception? What is "the first line"? Please compare Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId in UI thread (form constructor), backgroundworker and inside invoke.

Comment: @JeffRSon Thanks for your help... but i cant post the whole code here. sorry. .I dont get any exception.How do i compare... ?

Comment: @JeffRSon I tried in background worker completed event too... not working..In the backgroud worker im adding images to the imagelistview.

Comment: That's why I wanted to see the DoWork method. I don't know what your imageListView1 is, but I suppose it must be filled from the GUI thread too, and items must be created from GUI thread a.s.o. Try to put all these thing into an Invoke wrapper. This may block your GUI thread a bit, but if you know where's the problem you may rework the code.

Comment: @JeffRSon It seems that the issue comes when i add a single image..actually the image is selected in the image list view but the selection changed event do some processing .. the selection changed event is not firing ..so i cant see any update.Please see this message i have posted http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5230816/Programtically-Selecting-the-item-not-working-when.aspx